# JMS Serializer return Resource id #xxx on Mysql BLOB deserialize

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, jms

I'm working with JMS serializer on an Symfony 3 project.
When I read an entity with a blob value, the json returns: `Resource id #xxx`

Is the blob type not supported by default? How can I work with this?

Answer (score 4):

I solved this by making the getter always unwrap the resource for you and force JMS Serialiser to use that getter instead of default - reflection.

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="blob")
 * @Serializer\Type("string")
 * @Serializer\AccessType("public_method")
 */
private $payload;

public function getPayload(): string
{
    if (\is_resource($this->payload)) {
        return stream_get_contents($this->payload);
    }

    return $this->payload;
}

public function setPayload(string $payload): void
{
    $this->payload = $payload;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use : `<?= get_resource_type($data_example) ?>`
if return type = stream 
you can use `<?php stream_get_contents($data_example); ?>`

good luck!